# Looking for an approach to make sure my shell script runs only once when running it using crontab

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have a requirement to scan log file continuously and capture the exceptions and alert registered email users regarding the error.
To do the same I am doing "tail" on target log file and capturing the exceptions. This is happening properly.

Now I need to ship it to multiple servers on which I need to perform the same task. I also have set of other scripts which are to be run periodically. I have configured them in crontab and they are running fine.

I am looking for approach to configure this log script also on cron.
Lets say I configure it to run every one hour.
But I need to make sure the script execution is triggered only if the script is not already executing.

I have found following approaches to make sure of the same:
1) creating a flag file in the beginning of script only if the flag file does not exist already. if the flag file is already existing, exit the script with status 1, otherwise execute the actual code.
2) using flock

Please suggest which approach is better in context of my requirement.
Is it okay to use cron or do I need to put the script in startup (I prefer not to configure the script in startup because I would require further permissions for the same)

I apologize for longevity of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also search for your script name in the results of `ps -aux`. If you find it listed, terminate.